# error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'bool' to 'CString'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2005

I am getting the following error:

> C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'bool' to 'CString'

for the following code:

```
if ((CString)XSave->GetVersionAt(j).HasService_Ref())
    m_pVersion->SetstrServicesRef((CString)XSave->GetVersionAt(j).GetService_Ref());
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the returning type of `GetService_Ref()`? What is accepting type of `SetstrServicesRef()`?

Comment: I think you'll need to add some extra parentheses.

Comment: Don't use C-style casting in C++!

Comment: What do you try to check by such `if` condition? It will be always true because `CString` will be implicitly converted into `PCXSTR` (actually `const char*`) that is never NULL with MS implementation. Possibly you need to use `CString::IsEmpty()` function result. Or just remove `CString` cast from `if` condition.

Comment: Got it! Looks like `HasService_Ref` returns `bool` but you casts it to `CString` occasionally, by copy-paste I believe :-)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `HasService_Ref` returns `bool` but you casts it to `CString` occasionally inside `if` condition. Remove the cast and it shall work.